# appending ubuntu system path so i dont have to do sys.path in python

Tags: ubuntu, python

I am having an issue with my mod_wsgi on my apache2 server in Ubuntu.

Python can't find imported modules unless i append the sys.path

Every time i want to run a python script that imports classes inside modules, i have to append the system path

```
sys.path.append('/home/ubuntu/.wsgi/modules/')
```

how can i just add this to the ubuntu system so i dont have to run this all the time?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by doing:

```
# export PYTHONPATH=/home/ubuntu/.wsgi/modules/
```

as suggested by Andrew Clark at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271494/what-sets-up-sys-path-with-python-and-when

Which changed my sys.path in python which lead me to doing a reconfuration my my apache2 virtual host

```
WSGIScriptAlias /app/modules /home/ubuntu/.wsgi/modules/
```